# How to call a Web App only available to users inside domain from another google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, urlfetch

I have a Google script deployed as a web app, unfortunately, due to the company policy, I have to deploy it and make it available to anyone inside the domain, not anyone even anonymous.

Here's the web app code

```
function doPost(e) {
    var functionName = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents).functionName;
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({result:functionName}))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);  
}
```

Here's the Google Script code that I'm trying to call the web app through it, I tried to pass an access token in the request header.

```
function callWebApp(functionName) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
    },
    contentType: 'application/json',
    muteHttpExceptions:true,
   method : 'post',
    payload:JSON.stringify({functionName: functionName}),
  
  });

  Logger.log(response)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the `Session` service and filter out users who are not in your company domain.

For example:

```
var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

if(user.split('@')[1] === 'your.company.domain') {
  //do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately, this isn't the case here. I have two Google Scripts, one as a bounded script and the other is deployed as a web app. Due to the company restrictions from the Google Admin console, the web app can't be deployed such that it is available to anyone even anonymous. Due to that, the bounded script can't connect to the web app and I get unauthorized code.

Comment: I see. I don't think it is possible to do then, however, if you find out it is possible then please post what you find!